# Altering the chapter command causes bibliography to be treated as a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have redefined the chapter command to autolabel all chapters:

```
\renewcommand\chapter[1]{
  \capitalizewords[q]{#1}
  \noblanks[q]{\thestring}
  \origchapter{#1}\label{chap:\thestring}}
```

This works great, except I find that it causes a bibliography, created with **biblatex** and the `\bibliography` command, to be rendered incorrectly as a chapter rather than as the bibliography. The bibliography title page is messed up (says "Chapter WHATEVERCHAPTERNUMBER: *") and the table of contents lists "*" as a chapter. Otherwise the bibliography is rendered correctly. Anyone know what is causing this? I will be happy with a hacky solution, like an if statement in the `renewcommand` block that prevents just calls the original chapter command when it's handling the bibliography.

#### Minimal Working Example

The bibliography is being generated with a template. I have extracted the following code from the template file to create a minimal working example. Compiling the code below won't produce a table of contents, but it does produce the Bibliography as a Chapter named "*":

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[noadjust,verbose,sort]{cite} %   arranges reference citations neatly

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ls}[1]
   {\dimen0=\fontdimen6\the\font
    \lineskip=#1\dimen0
    \advance\lineskip.5\fontdimen5\the\font
    \advance\lineskip-\dimen0
    \lineskiplimit=.9\lineskip
    \baselineskip=\lineskip
    \advance\baselineskip\dimen0
    \normallineskip\lineskip
    \normallineskiplimit\lineskiplimit
    \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
    \ignorespaces
   }

\def\thebibliography#1{
\ls{1}
\chapter*{Bibliography\@mkboth
  {BIBLIOGRAPHY}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}}
  \markright{}
  %\thispagestyle{myheadings} % commented out to force page numbers to bottom center (8/11/07 change by C. St. Jean)
  %\thispagestyle{empty}
  \pagebreak
  \vskip 50pt
  \vspace*{0.61 in}%{0.75in}
  \centerline{\Large \bf Bibliography}\par \nobreak
  %\vskip 40pt
  \vskip 55pt
  \list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

\let\origchapter=\chapter
\renewcommand\chapter[1]{
  \capitalizewords[q]{#1}
  \noblanks[q]{\thestring}
  \origchapter{#1}\label{chap:\thestring}}

  % \tableofcontents

  \chapter{The Story of Life}
  Let there be light! \cite{Amaral:2007ua}

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{testbib}

\end{document}
```

You'll also need to put this in a bibtex file `testbib.bib`

```
@article{Amaral:2007ua,
author = {Amaral, DG and Lavenex, P.},
title = {{Hippocampal neuroanatomy}},
journal = {The Hippocampus Book},
year = {2007},
volume = {1},
number = {3},
pages = {37--114}
}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? Do you use biblatex or bibtex? The reason I ask is that with biblatex, one would use the command `\printbibliography` rather than `\bibliography` to make LaTeX insert the formatted bibliography (including sectioning header).

Comment: @Mico I'm using bibtex and a document class of report

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel MWE added. Thanks for the suggestion and your help!

Comment: So how do you want the bibliography to be rendered? Like a regular `\chapter*` (just a chapter heading but no `Chapter X` title)?

Comment: @Werner Yes, no Chapter X title-- the second page of the MWE output could be eliminated entirely, or it could say "Bibliography".

Comment: Just remove the `\chapter*{..}` from your `thebibliography` definition altogether. Also see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf\`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that you gain absolutely nothing with automatically generated labels. But the document is yours and, if you find convenient to call

```
\ref{chap:TheStoryOfLife}
```

then it's your problem and not mine. `;-)`

However, the error is in redefining `\chapter`, so that it can't recognize the `*` after it. You have to redefine the internal command `\@chapter` which is called when no * appears.

Another error is using `\@mkboth` in a context where `@` is not a letter.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Amaral:2007ua,
author = {Amaral, DG and Lavenex, P.},
title = {{Hippocampal neuroanatomy}},
journal = {The Hippocampus Book},
year = {2007},
volume = {1},
number = {3},
pages = {37--114}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[noadjust,verbose,sort]{cite} %   arranges reference citations neatly

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ls}[1]
   {\dimen0=\fontdimen6\the\font
    \lineskip=#1\dimen0
    \advance\lineskip.5\fontdimen5\the\font
    \advance\lineskip-\dimen0
    \lineskiplimit=.9\lineskip
    \baselineskip=\lineskip
    \advance\baselineskip\dimen0
    \normallineskip\lineskip
    \normallineskiplimit\lineskiplimit
    \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
    \ignorespaces
   }

\makeatletter
\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \ls{1}%
  \chapter*{Bibliography\@mkboth{BIBLIOGRAPHY}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}}%
  \pagebreak
  \vskip 50pt
  \vspace*{0.61 in}%{0.75in}%
  \centerline{\Large \bfseries Bibliography}\par \nobreak
  \vskip 55pt
  \list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}%
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

% redefine \@chapter
\let\orig@chapter=\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \capitalizewords[q]{#2}%
  \noblanks[q]{\thestring}%
  \orig@chapter[#1]{#2}\label{chap:\thestring}%
}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Story of Life}
Let there be light! \cite{Amaral:2007ua}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained.